# How is elimination reaction (E1) possible without base and in presence of acid?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, elimination, c-c-addition

When learning about E1 we were taught that three things are important factors to judge if the reaction is E1 or E2

1. Substrate ( 3,2,1 favours E2 but only 3 favours E1 )
2. Base ( Stronger Base favours E2 , weaker Base disfavours E2 hence suggests E1 ) But E1 requires a base however weak
3. Leaving group ( E1 is more sensitive to LG because it initiates E1 ) Bad LG disfavours both , excellent LG favours E1 more

This was from David M Kleins Book " Organic Chemistry I as a Second Language "
But in Section 11.6 he says this
[image: Markonikov addition of OH and H]

> fact, the reverse path (starting from the alcohol and ending with the alkene) is a reaction that we have already studied. **It is just an E1 reaction**

Then he goes on to show this picture
[image: Equilibrium between addition of OH and H markonikov and Elimination of OH]

Initial question : How do you have an elimination reaction without a base, that too in the presence of an acid ?
(Although I understand that E1 's rate doesnt depend on a Base but it is still needed)
Answer : there is a Base ( H20) which makes it look very much like E1 .

Edit : it behaves very much like an E1 but with an extra step

Step 0: converts the bad LG to an excellent LG

Step 1: LG leaves

Step 2 : Base abstracts proton to make alkene

New question:  Why does water behave like a base in an acidic mixture? And why does it not react with the H+ already in the solution ?

Comment: you are dehydrating an alcohol.. why not? Also, no, base is not needed for all E1 reactions..

Comment: then what are the necessary conditions for E1 reaction ?

Comment: so first of all, concentrated H2SO4 also has some amounts of water in it, so you have a base to work with. I think, "Why does water behave like a base in an acidic mixture? And why does it not react with the H+ already in the solution?" is indeed possible, but this reaction is in equilibrium forming some definite amounts of both. So, water is anyway abstract a proton.